# Permanently add an SSH key

Tags: git, bash, ssh

To get access to my remote git I add a reference to the SSH every time I push or pull:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_bit_rsa" git pull origin master
```

Is there a way to have the git remember the SSH so I don't need to add it each time?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Git doesn't care about your SSH keys. Behind the scene it invokes `ssh`. If the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` is set then it doesn't use `ssh` but the content of the `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` variable.

One option to make it permanent is to write:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_bit_rsa"
```

in your `.profile` (or `.bash_profile`) but it produces more harm than good if you use more than one remote hosts.

The correct way to solve it is to properly configure `ssh`. Edit the file `~/.ssh/config` (or create it if it doesn't exist) and put into it:

```
Host bitbucket.com
User guy
IdentityFile = ~/.ssh/id_bit_rsa
```

Of course, replace `bitbucket.com` with the actual name of the server that hosts your Git repo (I guessed BitBucket from the "*bit*" part of your key file) and `guy` with your name on the host.

Answer (score 6):

You could do this:

```
Host github
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_github
```

(replacing the user and hostname as needed, as well as the identity file)

in `~/.ssh/config`

Comment: It worked for me only with Host, User and IdentityFile fields. HostName was not used in key searching for some reason. Kubuntu 20.04.