# How can I add an already generated SSH key to git bash?

Tags: bash, git, ssh, putty, ssh-keys

I have an SSH key saved in `D:/keys folder`. I want to add it to my git bash. All the tutorials I found is how to generate SSH key using gitbash and load it to github/gitlab. I generated my SSH key using puttygen. Now I want to add it to my git bash so that I can clone a repository from remote. How can I do that?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

On windows you might need to start the ssh agent like this

```
# start the ssh-agent in the background
$ eval $(ssh-agent -s)
> Agent pid 59566
```

Add your SSH private key to the ssh-agent. If you created your key with a different name, or if you are adding an existing key that has a different name, replace id_rsa in the command with the name of your private key file.

`$ ssh-add <path/to/key>`

Got this information from here under "Adding your SSH key to the ssh-agent": 
https://help.github.com/en/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent#adding-your-ssh-key-to-the-ssh-agent

Comment: it works but how to make this permanent? I have to repeat each time I restart git bash

Comment: @Phate, Did you manage to understand how to add this permanently and repeat for every restart

Comment: One way I guess would be to add it to the `.bashrc` file?

Comment: @Phate This answer helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46661525/permanently-add-an-ssh-key

The idea is to create (or update) a file named 'config' in your .ssh folder with, for instance for bitbucket, the following lines adapted to your needs:

Host bitbucket.org
User yourbitbucketusername
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/yourkey

Answer (score 8):

I don't think there is any specific config in gitbash itself. You have to put the key in the default location `~\.ssh/id_rsa` and it will be used. If you need to have it somewhere else you could do so with a config file same as on Linux `~/.ssh/config`

```
host example.com
 HostName example.com
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 User git
```

Don't forget to set the permissions `chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa`

Answer (score 8):

Assume the private key file you want to import to git bash is `D:/keys folder/myprivatekey` and your Git was installed in `D:/Git` (in which folder you would see the binary file `git-bash.exe`), open the file `D:/Git/etc/ssh/ssh_config`.

Here are some texts in this file:

> ... 
> #   StrictHostKeyChecking ask 
> #   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
> #   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa 
> #   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
> #   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 
> #   Port 22 
> ...

Simply add a new line and save it:

> ... 
> #   StrictHostKeyChecking ask 
> IdentityFile "D:/keys folder/myprivatekey" 
> #   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa 
> #   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa 
> #   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ecdsa 
> #   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 
> #   Port 22 
> ...

And the key is already added.

Comment: In my case, Windows 11, Git Bash is installed under the Program Files folder and the file I was looking for is at C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh\ssh_config. Also, remember run GIt Bash as administrator, otherwise you will get permission restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it so the passphrase is only prompted for on the first window that's opened after booting using the script at [Auto-launching ssh-agent on Git for Windows](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/working-with-sshkey-passphrases#auto-launching-ssh-agent-on-git-for-windows). I did find, however, it didn't work when I added it add it to either `~/.profile` or `~/.bashrc`. I needed to add it to `~/.bash_profile` for it to get picked up and used by Git Bash on Windows.